# java.io.EOFException (32109) when running Eclipse Paho simulator with example Hono client

Tags: java, mqtt, paho, eclipse-hono

I am using MQTT simulator script that uses the Java [Eclipse Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/java/index.php) library. I did the device registration, set the device-id, tenant-id manually using the git bash terminal as per the instructions in the [Hono getting started guide](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/getting-started/), started the example hono client also with the instructions from the getting started guide and then ran this simulator code.

```java
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

public class MqttPublishHeartRate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String topic = "telemetry";
        String content;
        // int qos = 2;
        String mqttAdaptorIp = "tcp://10.103.102.133:1883";
        String tenantId = "f9ea5afe-2c11-4ab8-aa72-f2dd5df028a9";
        String deviceId = "713af6cc-f06c-4b1d-bfd2-2a2e0811a35e";
        String password = "password";
        MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

        try {
            while (true) {
                wait(10000);
                content = "{\"heartrate\":" + heartRateRandom() + "}";

                MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(mqttAdaptorIp, tenantId, persistence);
                MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
                connOpts.setUserName(deviceId);
                connOpts.setPassword(password.toCharArray());
                connOpts.setKeepAliveInterval(15);
                connOpts.setConnectionTimeout(30);

                System.out.println("Connecting to broker: " + mqttAdaptorIp);
                sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
                System.out.println("Connected");

                System.out.println("Publishing message: " + content);
                MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(content.getBytes());
                // message.setQos(qos);

                sampleClient.publish(topic, message);
                System.out.println("Message published");

                sampleClient.disconnect();
                System.out.println("Disconnected");
            }
        } catch (MqttException me) {
            System.out.println("reason " + me.getReasonCode());
            System.out.println("msg " + me.getMessage());
            System.out.println("loc " + me.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.out.println("cause " + me.getCause());
            System.out.println("excep " + me);
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void wait(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
    
    public static int heartRateRandom() {
        int heartRate = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 60;
        return heartRate;
    }
}
```

But I get this exception:

```
Connecting to broker: tcp://10.103.102.133:1883
reason 32109
msg Connection lost
loc Connection lost
cause java.io.EOFException
excep Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException
Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:181)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:133)
    ... 6 more
```

My Hono setup is in a local minikube and this is the output from kubectl get service.

```sh
c:\Users\HP>kubectl get service -n hono
NAME                                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                           AGE
eclipse-hono-adapter-amqp-vertx                 LoadBalancer   10.107.174.140   10.107.174.140   5672:32672/TCP,5671:32671/TCP     3d17h
eclipse-hono-adapter-amqp-vertx-headless        ClusterIP      None             <none>           <none>                            3d17h
eclipse-hono-adapter-http-vertx                 LoadBalancer   10.101.233.249   10.101.233.249   8080:30080/TCP,8443:30443/TCP     3d17h
eclipse-hono-adapter-http-vertx-headless        ClusterIP      None             <none>           <none>                            3d17h
eclipse-hono-adapter-mqtt-vertx                 LoadBalancer   10.103.102.133   10.103.102.133   1883:31883/TCP,8883:30883/TCP     3d17h
eclipse-hono-adapter-mqtt-vertx-headless        ClusterIP      None             <none>           <none>                            3d17h
eclipse-hono-artemis                            ClusterIP      10.105.136.215   <none>           5671/TCP                          3d17h
eclipse-hono-dispatch-router                    ClusterIP      10.103.15.52     <none>           5673/TCP                          3d17h
eclipse-hono-dispatch-router-ext                LoadBalancer   10.104.151.34    10.104.151.34    15671:30671/TCP,15672:30672/TCP   3d17h
eclipse-hono-grafana                            ClusterIP      10.110.248.10    <none>           3000/TCP                          3d17h
eclipse-hono-prometheus-server                  ClusterIP      10.110.243.239   <none>           9090/TCP                          3d17h
eclipse-hono-service-auth                       ClusterIP      10.105.228.68    <none>           5671/TCP                          3d17h
eclipse-hono-service-auth-headless              ClusterIP      None             <none>           <none>                            3d17h
eclipse-hono-service-device-registry            ClusterIP      10.101.64.187    <none>           5671/TCP,8443/TCP                 3d17h
eclipse-hono-service-device-registry-ext        LoadBalancer   10.105.144.218   10.105.144.218   28080:31080/TCP,28443:31443/TCP   3d17h
eclipse-hono-service-device-registry-headless   ClusterIP      None             <none>           <none>                            3d17h
```

Please let know how to fix this.

Comment: can you also post the MQTT adapter's log from during the interaction with your client? You can print the adapter log to the console using `kubectl logs -f $MQTT_ADAPTER_POD_NAME -n hono` where `$MQTT_ADAPTER_POD_NAME` is the name of the MQTT adapter pod as output by `kubectl get pod -n hono`.

Comment: Here is the log - https://docdro.id/iJffFZe

Comment: You have posted just a very small fragment of the log. The interesting information is not contained ... Can you make sure that you capture all of the log output from the start up of the pod until after the interaction of your MQTT client with the adapter?

Comment: here is the full output from the terminal the logs command was run - https://docdro.id/mkq0Wts . The errors are ... invalid clientIdentifier: .... and ..... ClientErrorException: malformed credentials ... not sure what needs to be changed. the program uses the settings registered in the terminal

Comment: oh it seems like the entire txt log did not upload in docdruid. heres the new link - https://docdro.id/BOljVej

Answer (score 1):

Figured out, The password should be in the form of auth-id@tenant, e.g. sensor1@DEFAULT_TENANT (https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/user-guide/mqtt-adapter/)
So modified the code to:

```
String tenantId = "DEFAULT_TENANT";
String authId = "sensor1";
String username = authId+"@"+tenantId;
```

Putting it here just in case anyone else may face this.

Comment: indeed, that seems to have been the problem